# CoreData: update in background and reading in main thread causes dead lock

Tags: objective-c, core-data, deadlock

I'm displaying a table with some data to the user. As soon as the view is presented, I'm making a web call to see if there's updated data (asynchronously). When the service call returns, I'd like to update my core data and the view.

Unfortunately I'm often getting dead locks because the view reads the same data as the service call writes. How can I solve this?

When I pause the simulator as soon as it's frozen, the waiting threads are waiting at the following places:

Background (updating) thread: (psynch_cvwait)

```
[mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)
                              withObject:notification
                           waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Main thread: (psynch_mutexwait)
    performing a `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It feels to me, from the introductory text, that you are breaking the MVC model.  There should be only one object controlling the data and fetching it.  The view should talk to the controller who talks to the model.  There is no deadlock if only one object doe async calls.  That is just hunch anyway.

Comment: I don't get it... I do have only one ViewController; the view asks this controller for the data (which performs a `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`). The same ViewController starts an async web service call (viewWillAppear) which, after return, writes the data to the database. So I do have only one object doing the async calls, but I nevertheless get a deadlock.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an actual solution to your problem? I've got a similar situation (finally!) trapped in the debugger, but I'm not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` will block the main thread.  That call will lock both `NSManagedObjectContext` instances while it updates the main context with the changes being passed in.

This is generally considered unavoidable in pre-iOS 5 applications.  You can minimize it by making more frequent, smaller, saves but it is still going to happen.

The only other option for pre-iOS 5 applications is to tell the main context to `-reset:` but that will require re-fetching everything -- another delay.

Comment: If it is a pure iOS 5.0 application then the parent/child contexts can be used which remove the need to mergeChanges and removes the block entirely.

Comment: how does that work? is there some tutorial/documentation about this parent/child context handling?

Comment: @swalkner There is documentation in the `NSManagedObjectContext` and there is a video from WWDC 2011.  I have also done a video course with iDeveoper.tv that should be coming out soon.

Comment: Hmm, how can a deadlock be unavoidable, if you're within the parameters of the documented API? The Core Data would be pretty sad indeed...

Comment: It is a block not a deadlock.  Two completely different things.  When the merge happens is blocks the threads as the background thread is blocked waiting for the main/UI thread to update.  The main/UI thread is blocked because it is processing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the main thread is trying to grab some low level lock that the background thread already has (or vice versa).  Are you using `@synchronized` somewhere to provide mutex?

Anyway, is there any reason why your background thread needs to wait for `-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` to complete?  If not, pass `NO` as the last parameter.

Comment: I'm not using `@synchronized`... and passing `NO` to `-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` didn't help either, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (lock on psynch_cvwait) when I was merging context changes (both ways) between the main and a background context (both using `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`).  The problem was caused by subscribing to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` on a different queue from which it was sent:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
object:mainContext
queue:bgQueue
usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
  // bgContext runs on bgQueue
  [bgContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
}]
```

As a result the block was never called, and both main and background queues hung on `psynch_cvwait()`

I fixed it by not blocking mainContext's queue:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
object:mainContext
queue:nil
usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
    [bgQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [bgContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
    }];
}]
```

However, it doesn't seem to be a problem if I block the background queue when merging changes into the main context.